# ksh - how to execute command in parametric way?

Tags: sh, psql, ksh

I have below psql command which working fine:

```
psql --echo-queries -v ON_ERROR_STOP=0 -v GROUP_ID=${id} ${PS_USER}:${PS_PASS}@${PS_INST}:${PS_PORT}/${PS_DB} << EOF 1 > ${log_file} 2>&1
\set AUTOCOMMIT OFF
INSERT INTO city (city_id, city, country_id)    VALUES (1000,'TEST1', 1);
EOF
```

I'd like to have the code cleaner by preparing the connection string in advance and execute when needed,
something like:

```
#preparing the connection string
ps_connection="${PS_USER}:${PS_PASS}@${PS_INST}:${PS_PORT}/${PS_DB}"


psql --echo-queries -v ON_ERROR_STOP=0 -v GROUP_ID=${id} ${ps_connection} << EOF 1 > ${log_file} 2>&1
\set AUTOCOMMIT OFF
....
EOF
```

When i do the same with sqlplus it is working:

```
sqlplus -s $curr_connection << EOF  1>> ${log_file} 2>&1 
....
```

What's the reason it doesnt work with psql?

I'm also good with preparing the full psql command,
i tried eval and exec and didnt work:

```
ps_connection="psql --echo-queries -v ON_ERROR_STOP=0 -v GROUP_ID=${id} 
 ${PS_USER}:${PS_PASS}@${PS_INST}:${PS_PORT}/${PS_DB}"

#also tried exec ${ps_connection}
eval ${ps_connection} << EOF 1 > ${log_file} 2>&1
\set AUTOCOMMIT OFF
....
EOF
```

Getting :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does happen and how is that different from the expectation?

Comment: @glennjackman - I edit the post with error i'm getting ,hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Perhaps the script file contains DOS-style line endings, so the `ps_connection` string ends with a `\r` character. I don't know if that would trigger that particular error though.